# Testing class methods with pytest - error - fixture 'self' not found

Tags: python, pytest

I want to test a class method with `py.test` and I've followed this post [Testing class methods with pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39395731/testing-class-methods-with-pytest).

I've got a file with my method (`calgo.py`) and another file with my test (`test_calgo.py`), and both files are in the same folder (`learning_ut`).

When I run pytest I get an error message saying `fixture 'self' not found`.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

```
# calgo.py 
class MyClass():
    def func(self, x):
        return x+1

# test_calgo.py
import calgo 
def test_func(self):
    mc = MyClass()
    assert mc.func(3) == 4

# Command line 
(pyenv) C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\learning_ut>pytest 

# Error message
(pyenv) C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\learning_ut>pytest
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.13, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\learning_ut
collected 1 item
test_calgo.py E   [100%]
======================================================= ERRORS ========================================================
_____________________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_func _____________________________________________
file C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\learning_ut\test_calgo.py, line 11
  def test_func(self):
E       fixture 'self' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, 
doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, 
record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
C:\Users\Jimmy\Desktop\learning_ut\test_calgo.py:11
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
ERROR test_calgo.py::test_func
```

Comment: What is `self`? Did you mean: `def test_func():`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self

Comment: Shouldn't it be `mc = calgo.MyClass()`

Comment: @CoryKramer: I reckon that will be the next problem.

Comment: thanks guys, I changed def test_func(self): to def test_func(): and mc = MyClass() to mc = calgo.MyClass(). The code works now.

Comment: @Jimmy I know it's been a while, but if you're still around, would you consider posting that as an answer to better help future readers of this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `pytest`, in `unittest` you create a test class, which would have method belonging to this class and have `self` as parameter. However, your error seems to be causes by the function in `calgo.py`, which does not belong to a class, thus does not have the self reference. Try the following:

```py
import calgo 
def test_func():
    mc = MyClass()
    assert mc.func(3) == 4
```

Comment: The problem is not related nor to pytest neither to unittest. That is only python syntax